# Put OSM (OpenStreetMap) in custom shape

Tags: android, openstreetmap

Is it possible to put OpenStreetMap in custom shape like the one in the picture below.

[image]

I tried to put the map in Linear Layout with background of the custom shape but this is a result.

[image]

This is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="550dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@drawable/jezicak_mapa"
    android:translationZ="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is a shape I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size
        android:height="630dp"
        android:width="375dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="66dp"
        android:topRightRadius="66dp" />
</shape>
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong, thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you tried with Cardview?

Comment: @Black4Guy I just tried with CardView and it works, but now I have bottom radius. As I googled, it also needs to have some shape implemented as background to cancel the that. But againt when I put the shape nothing happens.

Comment: Please check MaterialCardview you can give shape to card view via style in MaterialCardView    https://material.io/develop/android/theming/shape/